# Single downloads logged multiple times for iOS devices on ColdFusion 2016 / IIS 10 / HTTP/2

Tags: ios, coldfusion, http2, iis-10, coldfusion-2016

I have multiple file downloads working using this code:

```
<cfoutput query="RetrieveFiles">    
<a href="downloads/?id=#FileID#">Download #FileName#</a><br>
</cfoutput>
```

The downloads are then delivered using:

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#RetrieveFile.FileName#">
<cfcontent file="#RetrieveFile.FileName#">
```

Each download is recorded in the database:

```
<cfquery datasource="#datasource#">
    INSERT INTO FileLog
            (
                FileID
            )
            VALUES
            (
                <cfqueryparam value="#RetrieveFile.FileID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            )
</cfquery>
```

This all works fine, except for downloads from iOS devices, which can record each download 1000 times - in my logs and in the IIS logs - which Hostek tells me is because 'There is a known bug with CF2016, IIS10, iOS, and HTTP/2.'

I can disable HTTP/2, which fixes the issue, but I was wondering if there's a way to log each download on the ColdFusion side - only once - without disabling HTTP/2?

Comment: Off topic, but do you have something to prevent a user from downloading any file they want?

Comment: @Shawn yeah, certain users can only download certain files, but i didn't include any of that above

Comment: What is the bug number? Is this the Safari/HTTP2 bug where it'll just keep trying to reconnect to the page? And how are you calling the logging code? If they click the button, or go to the download page, it's probably safe to log a download attempt. Log it before calling the code to retrieve the file and redirecting.

Comment: Might the known bug be https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4198446? Could be others.